# How to get the current GPS time?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm trying to figure out how to get the gps time from the gps sensor on the phone device, however in the documentation I'm only able to find info for getting the current position. The object GeoPosition.Timestamp seems to return the current time that is on the device not the time from the GPS satellites.

Comment: How can you tell the diffrence between GeoPosition.Timestamp and the current time? They should be only miliseconds diffrent

Comment: I change the current time to something totally incorrect. this is how I know it's following the current time and not the gps time.

Comment: Why do you need to get the GPS time? Firing up the GPS will take more  battery power compared with the using the normal system time.

Comment: I need to get the time from the US atomic clocks.

Comment: @PaulAnnetts One reason would be because GPS time is accurate and the normal system time is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, i do not know the answer but i can possibly lead you in a direction to get answers.

[GPS Time Server](http://www.ntp-time-server.com/gps-time-server/gps-time-server.htm)

hope this helps. :)